# OpenCv 3.3 Cuda Medianfilter generates 2/3 of image black

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I'm trying to use the cv::cuda::createMedianfilter function in OpenCV library.

This simple code produces an image which is 2/3 black, and only 1/3 is filtered.

```
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Mat src; Mat dst;
  src = imread("test.bmp", 1);
  cuda::GpuMat imageGpu(src),imageGpuOut;
  cuda::Stream stream;
  try
    {
        Ptr<cuda::Filter> filterX = cuda::createMedianFilter(CV_8UC1, 31);
        filterX->apply(imageGpu, imageGpuOut,stream);
        imageGpuOut.download(dst,stream);
        stream.waitForCompletion();
        imwrite("test_cuda31.bmp", dst);
    }
    catch (cv::Exception& e)
    {
        const char* err_msg = e.what();
        std::cout << "exception caught: " << err_msg << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Input image looks like this :[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czzm9.png)
Output image looks like this :[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz2bU.png)

I have tried several other images with different sizes and also different kernal sizes on the medianfilter. All with the same result.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I think it is because you read an image as RGB -> that is 3 channels, and in create median filter function you use CV_8UC1 -> that is 1 channel.... thus it will process 1/3 of the image... You should convert it to greyscale first or load it with 0 and not 1, maybe I am wrong, I have not used that much the CUDA module of OpenCV

Comment: @api55... That is correct reason for the problem being observed. Please add your comment as an answer so that the issue can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading an image  of 3 channels (BGR)

```
src = imread("test.bmp", 1);
```

then, you are using as if the source was only 1 channel

```
Ptr<cuda::Filter> filterX = cuda::createMedianFilter(CV_8UC1, 31);
```

then it will process only 1/3 of the pixels, and probably the image is initialized in all 0, thus the black pixels in the rest of the image.

Sadly, `cuda::createMedianFilter` only supports `CV_8UC1`, so it is not possible to change that, but you can load the image as an `CV_8UC1`

```
src = imread("test.bmp", 0);
```

or convert it to greyscale after the load.

I hope this solves your problem